# Is Chromium GTK+ theme lighter than the others?

Tags: themes, chromium, memory-usage

[image]

Or is it heavier? What other aspects could one consider here beside aesthetics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested out my chromium install (Version 24.0.1311.0 (164559)), and it turns out that the GTK Version has a slightly higher memory footprint.

I tested it by enabling and disabling GTK Theme, while checking the memory footprint (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>). I had killed all extensions to make sure they didn't affect the results. I also kept only the settings page open so as not to have webkit rendering affect it either.

My results were:

1. GTK Version - 157,676K
2. Classic Theme - 157,456K

So, there is a difference, but its too little to be of any relevance.

Answer (score 1):

Thnx to [Capt.Nemo](https://askubuntu.com/users/11736/capt-nemo) who showed me how to test this I made my own experiment, which should be seen as a complement to the his answer, that I'll set as definitive, in the sense that the differences are negligible: especially given that my results are different (GTK theme appears lightest)

Using Google Chrome 22.0.1229.94, also killed all extensions and let the help tab open

Results were:

GTK+theme
[image]

Classic theme
[image]

Aluminium theme from Chrome Web Store
[image]

(As a result, considering the "Classic theme" as a sort of "no theme" situation, and comparing the other two, I go for the GTK theme.)

Also, it is possible that the GTK theme would give different results depending on the desktop environment. My test is made in Lubuntu 12.04 (LXDE).